# How to open the scratch buffer at the press of a key in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I have started using the *scratch* buffer very frequently while editing my emacs files to keep some temporary scratch information and checklists while coding.

Every since I discovered that Org mode has checkboxes for checklists and other awesome goodness for structuring text, I would always like to have my *scratch* buffer open up in org-mode at the press of a single key-stroke by say binding it to the F12 key.

Also at startup I would like my scratch buffer to permanently open up in org mode.

Comment: I answered this previously over at emacs.stackexchange.com -- **Is it possible to create an org-mode *scratch* buffer?** --  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16493/2287  Use that answer and add at the very end:  `(global-set-key [f12] 'my-scratch-buffer)`